# How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag in Latest Browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, autofill

I have a page in my web app, that page need to save some configurations , include different usernames and passwords. But browsers autofill fills usernames and passwords of this pages with saved Login credentials. autocomplete="off" doesnt seems to work in latest browsers. Is there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Do you insert autocomplete in the starting form tag?

```
<form .... autocomplete="off">
```

It works correct in our web app.